# Tab Panel Listener not working

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, tabpanel

When try to call the function method in tab panel on click, method is calling in listener. Here my code,

```js
var homepnl=Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    id:'homepnl',
    width:'100%',
    height:'100%',
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

    defaults: {
        styleHtmlContent: true
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'My Items',
            iconCls: 'star',
            id:'divtab1',
            items: [myitemspnl]
        },
        {
            title: 'Add Items',
            iconCls: 'compose',
            id:'divtab2',
            items: [additemspnl]
        },
        {
            title: 'Friend List',
            iconCls: 'team',
            //id:'friendsid',
            id:'divtab3',
            items:[friendslistpnl],
        },
        {
            title: 'Search',
            iconCls: 'search',
            items: [searchpnl]
        },
        {
            title: 'Settings',
            iconCls: 'settings',
            items: [settingspnl]
        }
    ],
        listeners: {
            tabchange: function (homepnl, tab) {
                alert(homepnl.id);// No alert is coming here
            }
        }
    });
```

What the problem with my code here? Please help me to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am looking at Sench touch documentation, there is no event `tabchange`. See [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel).

You can use [activeitemchange](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-activeitemchange) event.

Use below code in listeners :

```
listeners: {
    activeitemchange: function (homepnl, value, oldValue) {
        alert(homepnl.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is documented [for the tab bar](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Bar-event-tabchange), but apparently it never fires (see the comment)...

Comment: well `tab bar` is private and utility class which should not be used. And other thing is OP is using `tabpanel` which does not have such event.

Comment: Please don't let me be misunderstood. I don't say your answer is not good. I saw that there was such an event in the tab bar and that it doesn't seem to be implemented. I just felt compelled to comment on this... Who knows, it might even explain how the OP got confused in the first place.

Comment: :) I think OP used tabpanel like ExtJS. ExtJS tabpanel has `tabchange` event. See [tabchange Event in ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-tabchange)